# SwiftUI NavigationLink push in onAppear immediately pops the view when using @ObservableObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui

I want to programmatically be able to navigate to a link within a `List` of `NavigationLinks` when the view appears (building deep linking from push notification). I have a string -> Bool dictionary which is bound to a custom `Binding<Bool>` inside my view. When the view appears, I set the bool property, navigation happens, however, it immediately pops back. I followed the answer in [SwiftUI NavigationLink immediately navigates back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671119/swiftui-navigationlink-immediately-navigates-back) and made sure that each item in the `List` has a unique identifier, but the issue still persists.

Two questions:

1. Is my binding logic here correct?
2. How come the view pops back immediately?

```
import SwiftUI

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLinkActive:[String: Bool] = [:]
}

struct ContentViewTwo: View {
    @ObservedObject var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
    @State var data = ["1", "2", "3"]
    @State var shouldPushPage3: Bool = true

    var page3: some View {
        Text("Page 3")
            .onAppear() {
                print("Page 3 Appeared!")
        }
    }

    func binding(chatId: String) -> Binding<Bool> {
        return .init(get: { () -> Bool in
            return self.contentViewModel.isLinkActive[chatId, default: false]
        }) { (value) in
            self.contentViewModel.isLinkActive[chatId] = value
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        return
            List(data, id: \.self) { data in
                NavigationLink(destination: self.page3, isActive: self.binding(chatId: data)) {
                    Text("Page 3 Link with Data: \(data)")
                }.onAppear() {
                    print("link appeared")
                }
            }.onAppear() {
                print ("ContentViewTwo Appeared")
                if (self.shouldPushPage3) {
                    self.shouldPushPage3 = false
                    self.contentViewModel.isLinkActive["3"] = true
                    print("Activating link to page 3")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView() {
            VStack {
                Text("Page 1")
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewTwo()) {
                    Text("Page 2 Link")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Zorayr, the bug got fixed in the new SwiftUI release. Check my latest answer, hope it works for you!

Comment: check my answer for iOS 13 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121813/navigationlink-hides-the-destination-view-or-causes-infinite-view-updates

Answer (score 5):

The error is due to the lifecycle of the ViewModel, and is a limitation with SwiftUI NavigationLink itself at the moment, will have to wait to see if Apple updates the pending issues in the next release.

**Update for `SwiftUI 2.0`:**

Change:

```
@ObservedObject var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
```

to:

```
@StateObject var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
```

`@StateObject` means that changes in the state of the view model do not trigger a redraw of the whole `body`.

You also need to store the `shouldPushPage3` variable outside the `View` as the view will get recreated every time you pop back to the root `View`.

```
enum DeepLinking {
    static var shouldPushPage3 = true
}
```

And reference it as follows:

```
if (DeepLinking.shouldPushPage3) {
    DeepLinking.shouldPushPage3 = false
    self.contentViewModel.isLinkActive["3"] = true
    print("Activating link to page 3")
}
```

The bug got **fixed with the latest SwiftUI release**. But to use this code at the moment, you will need to use the beta version of Xcode and iOS 14 - it will be live in a month or so with the next GM Xcode release.

Comment: Thanks for following through so quickly.

Comment: No worries. Let me know if you have any issues after you test it!

Comment: I wasted so much time on this and eventually had to kill all `UINavigationView` and `UINavigationLink` and replace with `UINavigationController`. Never again `UINavigationView` until maybe a year from now, the effort is not worth the result and it's going to take time before people adopt 14.0 

Comment: It's not really ready for production code unless you're Apple

Comment: on button click adding item to an array from viewmodel, view pops back immediately. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

I was coming up against this problem, with a standard (not using 'isActive') NavigationLink  - for me the problem turned out to be the use of the view modifiers: .onAppear{code} and .onDisappear{code} **in the destination view**. I think it was causing a re-draw loop or something which caused the view to pop back to my list view (after approx 1 second).
I solved it by moving the modifiers onto a part of the destination view that's not affected by the code in those modifiers.