# SwiftUI deep linking with NavigationLink inside List onAppear with tag: and selection: doesn't activate link

Tags: swift, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui

Trying to build deep linking into a list of `NavigationList` items; I will be reading a value on the SwiftUI view's `.onAppear` and based on that value, navigate to a specific cell. There are three issues that come up with different setups I have tried: (1) with the below code, navigation doesn't happen at all, (2) if it does navigate, it will immediately pop back, (3) if programmatic navigation works and it doesn't pop back, the manual navigation doesn't work.

I have [tried this with a Binding dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62275502/swiftui-navigationlink-programmatic-navigation-inside-onappear-immediately-navig), and I get issue #2 above. Not only this, but in both solutions, user has to scroll to the cell in order to even read the binding/selection.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentViewTwo: View {

    var data = ["1", "2", "3"]
    @State var shouldPushPage3: Bool = true

    var page3: some View {
        Text("Page 3")
    }

    @State var selected: String?

    var body: some View {
        return
            List(data, id: \.self) { data in
                NavigationLink(destination: self.page3, tag: data, selection: self.$selected) {
                    Text("Tap for Page 3 with Data: \(data):")
                }.onAppear() {
                    print("link appeared.")
                }
            }.onAppear() {
                if (self.shouldPushPage3) {
                    self.selected = "3" // Has no affect. 
                    self.shouldPushPage3 = false
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView() {
            VStack {
                Text("Page 1")
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewTwo()) {
                    Text("Tap for Page 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd argue this is a bug with SwiftUI. I've experimented with your code and I can't find anything. Let's hope WWDC this month will bring a solid SwiftUI iteration.

Comment: Did you find a resolution? I'm getting the pop back behavior interactively clicking the list item.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispatch the selection.

```swift
.onAppear {
    guard shouldPushPage3 else { return }

    shouldPushPage3 = false
    DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        selection = "3"
    }
}
```