# How to prevent hidden SwiftUI view from redrawing from @Published variables?

Tags: swift, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui

I am building a chatting app: I have `InboxView` and `MessagesView`, to put it simply both are listening to a `@Published` variable called `chats`. When user sends a message in `MessagesView`, the ranking of inbox changes and because `InboxView` is listening to updates to chats `@Published` variable it redraws its views, regardless if the view is hidden! I am assuming this is some SwiftUI eager drawing optimization. Cool.

Now the problem is that `InboxView` has a `List` of `NavigationLink`s, which means during this redraw the `NavigationLink` somehow resets its state and navigates the user back!  Or even worse, pushes the user back to the same chat, again. You can see an [example setup here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292339/swiftui-deep-linking-with-navigationlink-inside-list-onappear-with-tag-and-sele), but what's missing is the data source.

I can't rely on `onAppear` or `onDisappear` because they are called as if the user navigates back to the view, so `InboxView` thinks it's being presented!

Comment: As this depends on views interaction it needs reproducible example. Would you provide code?

Comment: A view updates when an observed property changes (marked by `@ObservedObject`). If the list of navigation links does NOT depend on changes to the object containing your `@Published` chats, you can put the views that DO inside a child view. Do NOT use `@ObservedObject` in the InboxView, but rather in the child view. Without [reproducible example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is hard to give a better answer.