# NavigationLink hides the Destination View, or causes infinite view updates

Tags: swiftui, ios13, swiftui-navigationlink

Let us consider the situation when you have `ContentView` and `DestinationView`. Both of them depend on some shared data, that typically lies inside the `@ObservedObject var viewModel`, that you pass from parent to child either via `@EnvironmentObject` or directly inside `init()`.
The `DestinationView` in this case wants to enrich the viewModel by fetching some additional content inside `.onAppear`.

In this case, when using `NavigationLink` you might encounter the situation when the `DestinationView` gets into an update loop when you fetching content, as it also updates the parent view and the whole structure is redrawn.

When using the `List` you explicitly set the row's ids and thus view is not changed, but if the `NavigationLink` is not in the list, it would update the whole view, resetting its state, and hiding the `DestinationView`.

The question is: how to make `NavigationLink` update/redraw **only** when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SwiftUI the update mechanism compares View structs to find out whether they need to be updated, or not. I've tried many options, like making ViewModel `Hashable`, `Equatable`, and `Identifiable`, forcing it to only update when needed, but neither worked.

The **only** working solution, in this case, is making a `NavigationLink` wrapper, providing it with `id` for equality checks and using it instead.

```
struct NavigationLinkWrapper<DestinationView: View, LabelView: View>: View, Identifiable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: NavigationLinkWrapper, rhs: NavigationLinkWrapper) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    let id: Int
    let label: LabelView
    let destination: DestinationView // or LazyView<DestinationView>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: destination) {
            label
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `ContentView` use it with `.equatable()`

```
NavigationLinkWrapper(id: self.viewModel.hashValue,
                   label: myOrdersLabel,
             destination: DestinationView(viewModel: self.viewModel)
).equatable()
```

Helpful tip:

If your `ContentView` also does some updates that would impact the DestinationView it's suitable to use LazyView to prevent Destination from re-initializing before it's even on the screen.

```
struct LazyView<Content: View>: View {
    let build: () -> Content
    init(_ build: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.build = build
    }
    var body: Content {
        build()
    }
}
```

P.S: Apple seems to have fixed this issue in iOS14, so this is only iOS13 related issue.

Comment: Instead of using `AnyView` you can make your `NavigationLinkWrapper` generic (like you did with `LazyView`).

Comment: thanks, @pawello2222, I got so used to AnyView when writing UI, that forgot about my favorite generics which is totally a must in a standalone component.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Vivienne has worked for me, and is certainly worthy of consideration.

At other times, I have experienced similar situations and found that if I could remove the dependence of the detail view on environment objects, I could fix the infinite refreshing.

So a simple answer may be to remove those environment objects, perhaps passing them in via the `init` of the view instead. It's a relatively simple change that often works.